# RxSwift URLSession request is disposed

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm learning to use RxSwift and I'm stuck using this simple code. My intention is to take an APIRequest type, as simple as this:

```
public protocol APIRequest: Encodable {
    associatedtype Response: Decodable

    var path: String { get }
}
```

Pass it to the API Client and finally return an Observable of type `T.Response`, however, I'm constantly seeing `cancelled` status in my console:

```
2019-07-01 10:46:04.847: test api request -> subscribed
2019-07-01 10:46:04.855: test api request -> isDisposed
```

This is my APIClient's code:

```
func send<T: APIRequest>(_ request: T) -> Observable<T.Response> {
    guard let fullURL = endpoint(for: request) else {
        return Observable.error(APIError.invalidBaseURL)
    }

    return Observable<T.Response>.create { observer in
        let request = URLRequest(url: fullURL)
        let response = URLSession.shared.rx.response(request: request)
                              .debug("test api request")

        return response.subscribe(onNext: { response, data in
            if 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode {
                guard let responseItems = try? self.jsonDecoder.decode(T.Response.self, from: data) else {
                    return observer.onError(APIError.decodingFailed)
                }

                observer.onNext(responseItems)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
        }, onError: { error in
            observer.onError(APIError.other(error))
        }, onCompleted: nil,
           onDisposed: nil)
    }
}
```

I've been trying to get the results printed to the console with:

```
apiClient.send(countriesRequest)
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("Success", $0)
            }, onError: {
                print("Error: ", $0)
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("Completed!")
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: What do you do with return value of `func send<T: APIRequest>(_ request: T) -> Observable<T.Response>`?

Comment: @Andrew Added calling code.

Comment: I actually have that line, I miscopied it, sorry. I do have that line.

Comment: Do you nullify this `disposeBag` somewhere or create a new one?

Comment: At this moment, it's a `let disposeBag = DisposeBag()` as property in AppDelegate because I wanted to test the client out.

Comment: @jbehrens94 You can try use onDispose to determine why it dispose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to recreate your code, and it seem working fine on my device:

```
func send<T>(_ request: T) -> Observable<Data> {

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "sdf")!)

    return Observable.create { obs in
        URLSession.shared.rx.response(request: request).debug("r").subscribe(
            onNext: { response in
                return obs.onNext(response.data)
        },
            onError: {error in
                obs.onError(error)
        })
    }
}
```

I'm subscribing to it, and it produces an error

```
send("qwe").subscribe(
            onNext: { ev in
            print(ev)
        }, onError: { error in
            print(error)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you have a `response` property and recreate a `response` in the observer closure?

Comment: Oh no, just a mistake

Comment: I've tried out your code, but I'm still seeing the subscription disposed before anything is returned. I'm seeing this in my logs: `2019-07-01 11:39:44.850: test api request -> subscribed`
`2019-07-01 11:39:44.854: test api request -> isDisposed`
`Disposed`
`curl -X GET 
"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all" -i -v
Canceled (9115ms)`

Comment: Get rid of `.disposed(by: disposeBag)` in subscribe method. It seem there is the problem. And where do you invoke this request?

Comment: I think you are doing something with `disposeBag`) Because your request can be disposed only if you recreate it or nullify it. If you are getting `disposeBag` from `AppDelegate` in method it will exist only while method is executes, so probably it is your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195789/discussion-between-andrew-and-jbehrens94).